# Java string.replaceFirst problems

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace a part of a string. The part contains some special characters:

```
#L(inches)=24#
```

I know replaceFirst is regex driven but I can't seem to create a regular expression that matches this part in a string, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think maybe some markup got translated?  Can you say what you want to replace in a more general way?  Is it "on any line that begins with "#" and also has another "#", replace everything from one "#" to the other with an unrelated string?

Comment: Sean gave me a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#.*?#
```

This should match the entire String above.